# Show content on blade template depending the url

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to show some content depending on the url on ablade template but it's not working.

```
@if(Request::url() === 'myurl')
    // code
@endif
```

I cannot see `Request::url()` content I tried wir `dd`, `@dd`, `{{Request::url() }}`, but always I get the literal text.

what I  have to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(Request::is(''))
   // code
@endif
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching urls, use request pattern matching. In blade you can do.

```
@if(request()->is('user/yourroute'))    
    // code
@endif
```

Comment: how can I see the returned value of `request()->is('whatever')`?

Comment: {{request()->is('user/yourroute')}}

Comment: The template show `{{request()->is('user/yourroute')}}` literal ,not the returned value

Comment: then something is totally wrong, you sure the file is named correctly etc.? how do you load the view?